# How to parse data from a JSON to my actual element?

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I have this XHR request that passes data from a JSON file inside the folder to a actual `<p>` element but I cannot figure it out how to pass a specific data like "title" or "date".

JSON example:

```json
{
    "title": "Personal development webinar",
    "date": "21.04.2021",
    "time": "8:00 AM",
    "webinar": {
      "title": "Personal development webinar",
      "link": "https://meet.google.com"
    }
}
```

and my XHR request looks like this

```js
function showEvents() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
       console.log(this.responseText)
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "./events.json", true);
xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Please show us an example your desired output, that is how you'd like it to appear in the element with `id="demo"`.

Comment: yes, i want to show the specific data in my <p id="demo">Title: </p> like "Title: Personal development webinar. tried to make a var for that parse and use it like var.title but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you show what `JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);` prints to the console? That would help pinpoint exactly what's going on.

Comment: i get the full body of my json with all 4 objects

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/7Pex66e this is the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON.parse function returns an object yielding the JSON. In your case an array of objects, since you get all entries returned.
So you can access the single fields by addressing a single index of the array as object.
For example:

```
function showEvents() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           let jsonData = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = jsonData[0].webinar.title;
           console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "./events.json", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

This gets the first dataset.

Comment: Ah, I see from your console-screenshot, you get an array returned. In that case, I need to update my code.

Comment: yeah i just figured out right before you commented that i dont have an index of the element, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code just gets the data form the events file. But you never called the function showEvent() that's why it's not showing data in console. See the code below to have a hint how to do this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<style>
    .data-table
    {
        width: 100%;
        border: 2px double black;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
</style>
<body onload="showEvents()">
    <div id="demo">

    </div>


    <script>
        function showEvents() {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    let dataJson = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
                    displayResponseData(dataJson);
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "./data.json", true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
        function displayResponseData(data) {
            let table = ` 
            <table class="data-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Title</td>
                        <td>Date</td>
                        <td>Time</td>
                        <td>Webinar Title</td>
                        <td>Webinar LInk</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>${data.title}</td>
                        <td>${data.date}</td>
                        <td>${data.time}</td>
                        <td>${data.webinar.title}</td>
                        <td>${data.webinar.link}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
`;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=table;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's the output:

Comment: I do get the all the events.json data in my console but i cannot get a specific part of it in my <p>

Comment: Can I see your complete code?? Or you can get hint from my code I sent you, it's showing data in table.

Comment: Give me the code, I can debug it and explain it to you

Answer (score 0):

From the image you provided in the comments, it seems your returned data is an array of objects. You can print the values to the `<p>` element something like this:

```js
// the below var data resembles -> var data = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
var data = [
  {
      "title": "Personal development webinar",
      "date": "21.04.2021",
      "time": "8:00 AM",
      "webinar": {
        "title": "Personal development webinar",
        "link": "https://meet.google.com"
      }
  },
  {
      "title": "Test title",
      "date": "21.04.2099",
      "time": "11:00 AM",
      "webinar": {
        "title": "Just another webinar",
        "link": "https://meet.google.com"
      }
  }
];

let output = "";

for(obj of data) {
  output += obj.title + " - " + obj.date + " " + obj.time + "<br>";
  output += obj.webinar.title + ":  " + obj.webinar.link;
  output += "<br><br>";     // two new lines
}

document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```